# How to export the frequency tables (categorical data) and descreptive analysis (continuous variables) from a big dataframe from R into excel?

Tags: r, excel, frequency

I have this dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(x = c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1), y = c(2,2,2,2,3,3,2),
                z = 1:7, m = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1) )

df$x = factor(df$x)
df$y = factor(df$y)
df$m = factor(df$m)
```

I want to extract all the descriptive analysis information of each of these variables into excel in a simple way so I can present the results of my work.

Answer (score 0):

There is little information here and it unclear how you want to present this, but if you would like to get summary statistics (tables [categorical] and median/IQR [continuous]), you can use `lapply` across all columns. This will output as a list from which you can manipulate to export as you see fit.

Data

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                 y = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2),
                 z = 1:7,
                 m = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1))
cats <- c("x", "y", "m")
df[cats] <- lapply(df[cats], as.factor)
```

Run `lapply`

```
results_list <- lapply(df[1:ncol(df)], summary)
```

Output:

```
> results_list
$x
0 1 
3 4 

$y
2 3 
5 2 

$z
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    1.0     2.5     4.0     4.0     5.5     7.0 

$m
1 2 3 
3 2 2
```